# I want to model guns, but how do I model stuff like THIS?

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

On a lot of handguns, there are grooves on the slide to improve your grip when charging the handle. (racking the slide back to load a bullet into the chamber)

But how do I recreate these grooves? Do you just spam loop cuts?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121295/adding-detail-extruding-a-grill-type-part-at-top-to-a-box-mesh-without-affecti

Comment: That doesn't help. There wasn't a clear answer on how to model it. All there was   is the guy explaining what "slides" were. How do you model this? Loop cuts?

Comment: This is just a comment, given the good answers you've had already.. unless this model has to be manifold for 3D-printing or something, or you've got to reduce polys.... in RL, the slide is a separate part... so, IMO, there's no shame in modeling it as a separate part. There might be no need to compromise your topology by 'tying off' the edges to reduce edge-loops. The edge loops in a separate part won't propagate through the rest of your model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with Bevel and Array modifiers:

[image]

Or, as suggested by Lukasz-40sth, you can do it with an arrayed cube, and at the end, same, use tris to finish the topology:

[image]

Comment: I did variate from your solution a little bit by using an array & boolean after I've subdivided the model, rather than using all those bevels to smoothen it. Bevels seem like a pretty nice alternative to subdivision but they'd take a while for me to get used to them. Your solution, did, however, make me come up with that idea. THANKS!!

Comment: please check out, I've added the solution suggested by Lukasz-40sth

Comment: Very smart approach. However, Lukasz's solution seems to be flawed because it does not take account for the rest of the model. Unlike the boolean array approach, it doesn't look like you can just smack this into whatever you're working on. Interesting nonetheless

Comment: about the Bevels (and also Booleans): I've used the Speedflow addon, if you're interested in hardsurface topology, you should like, it speeds up the workflow very fast!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I could think about of for doing this based on the image you posted is using the loop cuts, I tried to recreate a quick similar situation on the images below:

**1) create a number of loop cuts (CTRL+R and mouse wheel to select how many cuts you want) equal to the double of the amount of that stuff you want.**

[image]

**2)select the edges alternately (where you want the lower part of that stuff) and move them backwards.**

[image]

**3) select the other edges that you avoided before and move them to the right, so that in ortho view they are exactly above or in front of the edges youmoved backwards.**

[image]

**4) Dissolve any unwanted additional geometry (like the edges above that split the triangle faces in two for example)**

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks! However, is this the only way I can really do this? I don't want too much artifacting going on around the whole model, and if you subdivided your example a little bit you'll see it has a bit of a weird pinching effect.

Comment: And this gun doesn't have grooves going along the entire side, halfway up there's no grooves. How should I make this effect?

Comment: Sorry, from the picture I thought it was something like that ahahahha. Another way I could think of is with loop cuts and extrude, or you could try with the boolean modifier, but this last one could give you weird topology.

Comment: No problem at all! I've found my solution. Combining yours and Moonboot's solution, I've decided to just boolean it *after* I subdivide it. That way subdivision doesn't freak out and I get a very nice shape afterwards. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

What if I told you it's a sheared cuboid, multiplied with **Array** modifier and fitted in with **Snap to the nearest edge**? As the finishing touch use Ctrl+J.